# Push button issue in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

This must be a simple question to solve, but I'm stuck on it. According to [CircuiTikZ Manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf) a simple push button is a `to[push button]` element in a circuit. But, in my case, it doesn't work!

Show the circuit code as I developed (When a `ospst` is shown, a push button should go):

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\draw 
  (-1,2) node[left] {$V_{PIN}$} to[short,o-] (0,2) %de -1,2 un nodo a través de una linea a 0,2
  to[R=$10K{\Omega}$] (0,0) node[ground] {} %y de ahí a R al ground
  (0,2) to[ospst,-o] (0,4) node[left=1mm] {$5V$} % y del 0,2 al 0,4 se dibuja el pulsador       
;
\end {circuitikz}
```

I'm using LYX in Ubuntu 12.10 and loaded the packages in Preamble:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
```

The package `circuitikz` is part of the package `texlive-pictures`, version 2012.2012611-4.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7):

The following code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\draw 
  (-1,2) node[left] {$V_{\textrm{PIN}}$} to[short,o-] (0,2) %de -1,2 un nodo a través de una linea a 0,2
  to[R=10<\kilo \ohm>] (0,0) node[ground] {} %y de ahí a R al ground
  (0,2) to[push button,-o] (0,4) node[left=1mm] {\SI{5}{\volt}} % y del 0,2 al 0,4 se dibuja el pulsador       
;
\end {circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

provides me:

[image]

with an updated version of TeXLive.

I suspect the problem comes from the fact that `push button` has been introduced in the newer version of `circuitikz`, but you do not have them installed. Traditionally, Ubuntu 12.10 packages for LaTeX were providing an old release (2009 if I'm correct). My personal recommendation, is to always install a complete version, i.e see [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)